# assign not working in grouped pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, assign, chaining

In a complex chained method using pandas, one of the steps is grouping data by a column and then calculate some metrics. This is a simplified example of the procedure i want to achieve. I have many more assignments in the workflow but is failing miserabily at first.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],'first':[1,12,4,5,4,3],'last':[5,3,4,5,2,7,]})

data.groupby('Group').assign(average_ratio=lambda x: np.mean(x['first']/x['last']))


>>>> AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

I know i could use apply this way:

```
data.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: np.mean(x['first']/x['last']))
Group
A    1.733333
B    1.142857
dtype: float64
```

or much better, renaming the column in the same step:

```
data.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'average_ratio':np.mean(x['first']/x['last'])}))

average_ratio
Group   
A   1.733333
B   1.142857
```

Is there any way of using .assign to obtain the same?

Comment: If you have more assignments, you can try create dataframe in `groupby.apply`.

Comment: It works in this way `data['average_ratio'] = data.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: np.mean(x['first']/x['last']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer last question, for your needs no you cannot. The method, [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) simply adds new columns or replace existing columns but return the same index `DataFrame` with new/adjusted columns.

You are attempted a grouped aggregation that reduces the rows to group level and thereby changing the index and `DataFrame` granularity from unit level to aggregated grouped level. Therefore you need to run your `groupby` operations without `assign`.

To encapsulate multiple assigned aggregated columns that aligns to chained process, use a defined method and then `apply` it accordingly:

```py
def aggfunc(row): 
    row['first_mean'] = np.mean(row['first']) 
    row['last_mean'] = np.mean(row['last']) 
    row['average_ratio'] = np.mean(row['first'].div(row['last'])) 

    return row


agg_data = data.groupby('Group').apply(aggfunc)
```